# Wanting to create a simple web service/api using only html page to aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rest, web-services, wcf

I have a simple html page where the user enters a FunctionName and it's Parameters and Submits the Call (see HTML text ):.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form action="process.aspx" method="post">
    GMailFunction <input type="text" id="GMFunction" name="GMFunction"   
    GMailParameters<input type="text" id="GMFParameters" name="GMFParameters"  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This Call gets answered by an ASPX page named process.aspx  containing only this code :

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private Sub _Default_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim GMFunction As String = Request.Form("GMFunction")
    Dim GMFParameters As String = Request.Form("GMFParameters")
    Response.Write(GMFunction)
    Response.Write(<br></br>)
    Response.Write(GMFParameters)
    Response.Write(<br></br>)
    Response.Write("Hello World FROM DEFAULT CLASS")
End Sub
End Class
```

Questions:
  1. In the html code, when I change the method to GET the request does not get treated. What do I need to change in my code ?
  2. If I wanted to bypass the HTML page to reach the aspx (like a web api) directly from let's say a windows program, how does the URL need to be formed for a GET and for a POST?

Answer (score 0):

Your calling the Process.aspx page with `action="process.aspx" method="post"`, the events in the codebehind are going to fire in a specific (known) order. `Partial Class Process` is not one of them, nor is it an event.  You have to call it yourself.  The simplest way is to call it in the load event, but then how are you going to get the response back to your html page?  You're going to need to code some javascript (jQuery is a good library) and maybe some ajax, ajax would probably be better.  A lot of what you do can also depend on your development paltform, I assume you're using Visual Studios, if so, what version?

Change your function to a webmethod (plenty of examples on stackoverflow), then call the webmethod using ajax:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.aspx/SomeWebMethod",
        // the parameter names must match webmethod parameter names exactly
        data: JSON.stringify({ parameter1Value: 'somedata', parameter2Value: 'moredata' }), 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Data sucessfully transmited.");
            // do stuff here on success like retrieve the data
            // easiest way is to set a public variable in the code behind with the data you want to retrieve
            // and then set a label's value to the data or some such.
            var thedata = '<%=PublicVariableInCodeBehind%>';
            // This assumes aspx page is calling the webmethod
            $("#<%=SomeLabelName.ClientID%>").val(thedata);
            // To set a html label with the data
            // $('#labelName').text(thedata);
            // You can also  do things like add a row and cells to a table and display the data that way, whatever you want to do.
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Error = " + response.responseText);
        }
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Thx Prescott, I reformulated the question, I think the original one was not clear.

Comment: My answer would be the same, that's not how asp.net (aspx) works.  At the most, the parameters are on a query string, you still have to execute the function from the codebehind.  What version of Visual Studios are you using?  It matters ... you need to call a webmethod.

Comment: Here's a good post:

https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/02/05/passing-net-server-side-data-to-javascript